# Gridview using html in ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, gridview

I have a doubt in gridview design can anyone help me.
 I have created a gridview, but when im giving any text to that grid cell my grid design is changing. My question is how to give a fixed height to the gridview even if we are entering text into one cell or no: of cells. And Here is my code.
 Thank You in Advance.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GrvSchoolName1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4"       Height="30px" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"    CellPadding="3" 
                    GridLines="Vertical" CssClass="grvclass"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"                           
                    ForeColor="Black" onpageindexchanging="GrvSchoolName1_PageIndexChanging">
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4"  FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"/> 
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />

            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emergency Alert" HeaderStyle-Height="30px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <div style="overflow:auto; height:60px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("AlertMessage") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
          </asp:GridView>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a css class to your itemstyle template. Same works for the header :)

**.NET**

```
<ItemStyle CssClass="items"> </ItemStyle>


<ItemTemplate>
your stuff
</ItemTemplate>
```

**CSS.**

```
.items{width:200px;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I need constant height for gridview, if we enter any datasource into single cell. can you please give any idea about the constant height.

Comment: do the same but replace width, with height. if you weant your total gridview a fixed hight try this: `#GridView1{height:500px;}`